# Modify this js function so that it uses the value fetched from the db instead of the values specified in the array to generate the Select options

Tags: php, javascript

How can I modify this function so that it can use the value fetched from the db instead of the values specified in the array used to generate the Select options?

The function allows me to differentiate between the default value of select elements (*or 'default state', which are pre-set to the most commonly chosen options)*, vs. when a user has actively chosen that value by clicking on the form element *(indicating that they made an active decision to leave it set to that value)*. The function works correctly in the initial form, and I've posted a fiddle with a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/JHAPp/4/

```
<script>
$('select').focus(function () {
    var option = $(this).find("option[value*=default]");
    option.attr('value', option.attr('value').replace(/_default/g, ''));
});
</script>
<select name="jeans">
    <option value="$0">$0</option>
    <option value="$50_default" selected="selected">$50</option>
    <option value="$100">$100</option>
    <option value="$150">$150</option>
</select>
```

I'm having trouble adapting the function to work on the account page, where users can review and edit their information. In the initial use of the function I could change the options values manually *(i.e. replacing `value="$50"` with `value="$50_default"`)*, however the account page uses $options array in the printSelectOptions functions below generate the  element's options in order to pre-select the options matching the db information. The function below pre-selects the values matching the information in the db (regardless of if the user specifically selected the value or if it's still in a 'default state'), however since it needs to remove the '_default' string in order to identify the correct option generated by the `$options` array it is submitting the value without the '_default' string, regardless of whether or not it's been changed.

How can I modify the js function to work in tandem with this so that if a user hasn't focused on the element it will submit the default value if the value was fetched from the db in the 'default state' (with the '_default' string)?

```
<?php
    try {  
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM price WHERE user_id = :user_id");  
        $stmt->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id); 
        $stmt->execute();
    }  catch(PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    $search_default = array('_default');
    $replace_default = array('');
    $row_default = str_replace($search_default, $replace_default, $row);

    // This function selects the option matching the value in the db
    function printSelectOptions($dataArray, $currentSelection) {
        foreach ($dataArray as $key => $value) {
            echo '<option ' . (($key == $currentSelection) ? 'selected="selected"' : '') . ' value="' . $key . '">' . $value . '</option>';
        }
    }
?>
<select name="jeans">
<?php

    // Generates a <select> element with the options specified in this array
    $options = array("Null"=>"", "$0"=>"$0", "$50"=>"$50", "$100"=>"$100", "$150"=>"$150");
    $selected = $row_default['jeans'];

    // Pre-selects the option matching the db information
    echo printSelectOptions($options, $selected); 
?> 
</select>
```

Comment: What colums your price table contain?

Comment: @jcubic - The column that this code is referencing is 'jeans' (There are apx. 200 columns in 'price')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider changing the PHP code, and leave the JavaScript as it is.

How about this:

Before your call to `echo printSelectOptions(...)`, find the entry in `$options` where the key equals `$row_default['jeans']` (which never ends with "_default") and change key of that entry to `$row['jeans']`. You might be just setting it to what it already was, but you might be changing it so it now ends with "_default".

You would also change `$selected = $row_default['jeans'];` to `$selected = $row['jeans'];`.

Now if the value from the database ends with "_default", the selected option (and only the selected option) will end with "_default". Since the JavaScript remains the same, it will remove the "_default" if the user focuses on the select element.

The code would look like this:

```
// This is a helper function that replaces a key while maintaining the entry's
// position in the array. It does not modify the given array, but returns a
// new array.
function replaceKey($array, $oldKey, $newKey) {
    $newArray = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $newArray[($key === $oldKey) ? $newKey : $key] = $value;
    }
    return $newArray;
}

$options = array("Null"=>"", "$0"=>"$0", "$50"=>"$50", "$100"=>"$100", "$150"=>"$150");

// We will change the key for the entry in $options so it includes "_default" if
// the value from the database includes "_default". We need to do this only if
// $row['jeans'] ends with "_default". That will be the case if these two are
// different.
if ($row_default['jeans'] !== $row['jeans']) {
    $options = replaceKey($options, $row_default['jeans'], $row['jeans']);
}

// Now we can use the value from the db for setting the selected value, rather
// than the value that had "_default" removed. 
$selected = $row['jeans'];

// Pre-selects the option matching the db information.
echo printSelectOptions($options, $selected);
```

UPDATE:

The JavaScript that executes when the select gains focus looks correct. I tested it in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/2epBy/) and it appears to work fine. If you look at the jsfiddle, I altered it some so it reflects the fact that the options end with "_default". I also changed the use of `.attr()` to `.prop()`, but the original worked as well. (If you are using jQuery >=1.6, you should use `.prop()` to change element properties, not `.attr()`.)

If the PHP is generating the select the way it looks in the jsfiddle, then there must be another reason the JavaScript is not working. Perhaps there is a JavaScript error that is causing the event handler to not get hooked up.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you. If the value in the db is '$50' (as opposed to '$50_default', because the user has already selected a price), would that leave it as '$50' or change it back to '$50_default')?

Comment: It would just leave it as '$50'. If you don't like that, you could first check if the value from the db ends with "_default" and not change the value in `$options` if it doesn't. That's what I was first going to suggest, but it's more code that way.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do :-D Would you mind showing me how I would do it?

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to do what I first suggested or the part where you check if the db value ends with "_default"?

Comment: What you first suggested :-)

Comment: Okay, I already made an attempt at adding the code to my answer. The first and last lines did not change. The second line is new, and the third line changed.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense :-) I'm going to try it first thing in the morning (when I'm less likely to make stupid mistakes ;-) )

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I think you are an hour ahead, and it's too late for me.

Comment: Unfortunately the keys and values aren't equal (for example, '_default' isn't shown to the user) :-( Would you mind showing me how to go about it with the other approach you mentioned?

Comment: The PHP is working perfectly with the new code, but for some reason it's preventing the js function from being triggered. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you so much for your incredible patience and for explaining everything so well :-) Since the function seems to work properly without the php I'm assuming that the problem has to do with the interaction between the two. I'll try to post that as a separate question tonight, and I'd welcome any other ideas you might have :-)

Comment: I just posted it - http://stackoverflow.com/q/15534078/1056713 (I struggled a bit with the phraseology, so I hope the question is clear)

Comment: @Chaya Cooper -  I cleaned up my answer, and it now includes a helper function to make the code more readable.

Comment: It's probably something minor, but the new function isn't working (the select element doesn't have any options and it submits an empty value).

Comment: Love the new notes :-D It'll be so much easier for someone looking at the code later to understand what's going on (including me ;-) )

Comment: @Chaya Cooper - The helper function had `$newOptions` where it should have had `$newArray`. Hopefully that was the only bug.

Comment: I figured it must be something like that ;-) I'll try it right now :-)

Comment: That fixed it, and I love how much simpler the code is now :-D One more quick thing before I can use it - About 1/2 of the <select> elements I'm using this with are prices, and I realized that it's not working with non-monetary values (values which don't have a '$'). How would I modify it to work with any string value?

Comment: @Chaya Cooper - It should work with any string value the way it is. There's certainly nothing in the code that would require the strings to include dollar signs. There must be something else going on that is causing the issue you are seeing.

Comment: I was surprised too, but I tested every possibility and that's the only thing that seems to be causing it. I put up a test page so that you could see what I was talking about at http://click2fit.com/sample_php_select.php I've hardcoded the values in the php for the elements to "$50_default" and "3_default", and if you press submit (without focusing on either <select> element it will echo the posted values ("$50_default" and "3")

Answer (score -1):

`$row` in your code is an array and you access field using $row['jeans'] and to return all rows you need to put `$stmt->fetch()` in loop.

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $row_default = str_replace($search_default, $replace_default, $row['jeans']);
    echo '<option value="' . $row_default . '">' . $row_default . '</option>';
}
```

Here is [fetch documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: Since this is a specific user's information, I only want to return the row with their information. The information is being fetched and displayed correctly, my problem is specific to how I want to allow them to edit that information and to be able to update it with values that aren't in the array which generates the <select> options