# PHP function to manipulate values isn't working unless string includes a dollar sign ('$')

Tags: php, javascript, string

The *PHP* & *JS* functions shown below work together to 1) Populate `select` elements from arrays 2) Pre-select the `options` matching the *db* values, and 3) Manipulate the value of `select` element `options` on `focus`.

The *PHP* helper function works in concert with the *JS* `focus` function, and manipulates the string values if the db value included the suffix '_default'), but it's only being triggered if the option/string value includes a dollar sign ('$'). There isn't anything in the code that should require this, but I've tested every possibility and that's the only thing that seems to be causing it.

I've posted a functional example with the combined code at http://click2fit.com/sample_php_select.php. To see the problem in action, click on the 'Submit' button without focusing on either `select` element, and it will `echo` the posted values for two `select` elements with 'default' values  -  one with a dollar sign and one without. For purposes of demonstrating the problem, I have hardcoded the values instead of fetching them from the *db*. In addition, I've posted a fiddle with *JS* function here http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/JHAPp/6/

*PHP & HTML*

```
<?php
// Helper function that replaces a key while maintaining the entry's position in the array. It does not modify the given array, but returns a new array.
function replaceKey($array, $oldKey, $newKey) {
    $newArray = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $newArray[($key === $oldKey) ? $newKey : $key] = $value;
    }
    return $newArray;
} 
// Function to select the option matching the value in the db
function printSelectOptions($dataArray, $currentSelection) {
    foreach ($dataArray as $key => $value) {
        echo '<option ' . (($key == $currentSelection) ? 'selected="selected"' : '') . ' value="' . $key . '">' . $value . '</option>';
    }
}
  try {  
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM price WHERE user_id = :user_id");  
    $stmt->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id); 
    $stmt->execute();
}  catch(PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$search_default = array('_default');
$replace_default = array('');
$row_default = str_replace($search_default, $replace_default, $row);
?>

<select name="importance" id="importance">
<?php
    // Generates a <select> element with the options specified in this array
    $options = array("1"=>"1", "2"=>"2", "3"=>"3", "4"=>"4", "5"=>"5");
    // If these are different then the value from the database includes "_default"
    if ($row_default['importance'] !== $row['importance']) {
        // Change the key for the entry in $options so it includes "_default" 
        $options = replaceKey($options, $row_default['importance'], $row['importance']);
    }
    $selected = $row['importance'];
    // Pre-selects the option matching the db information
    echo printSelectOptions($options, $selected);
?>
</select>
```

*JS Function*

```
 $(function () {
     $('select').focus(function () {
         var option = $(this).find("option[value*=default]");
         option.attr('value', option.attr('value').replace(/_default/g, ''));
     });
 });
```

*Purpose of JS function*

I am pre-selecting the most commonly chosen options for apx. 300 `select` elements, and am using this function to differentiate between when those values are still in their initial pre-selected/default state vs. when a user has actively chosen that value after focusing on the form element.

Answer (score 1):

`option` doesn't get any value and `replace` doesn't work well with jQuery.

Change this:

```
$(function () {
  $('select').focus(function () {
     var option = $(this).find("option[value*=default]");
     option.attr('value', option.attr('value').replace(/_default/g, ''));
  });
});
```

To this:

```
$(function () {
  $('select').focus(function () {
    var default_option = $("option[value*=default]"); // Just added this part to a variable, for easy of use.
    var option = default_option.val(); // Got the option value that contains the word default.
    // This will replace the '_default' with '' and assign the new value to the option
    default_option.val(function(index, value) {
      return value.replace(/_default/g, '');
    });
  });
});
```

But javascript is not your only problem. You have a lot of problems in the php code and I am afraid you have made it more complicated than it actually is.

Comment: It's still showing Importance as '3' instead of '3_default' :-(

Comment: I just updated the question because I realized that the problem is that the PHP 'helper' function - which manipulates the string values - isn't getting triggered

Comment: `$options = replaceKey($options, $row_default['importance'], $row['importance']);` is wrong. What exactly do you think `php` does in this case?

Comment: Maybe you have to reconsider your whole code structure. You have a lot of coding problems too. Also, study how `php arrays` work. Or give this to an expert to build it for you.

Comment: As far as I understand, that should change the key for the entry in $options so it includes "_default" if the value from the database includes "_default". I actually created the PHP 'helper' function with the help of another SO member (in this posting http://stackoverflow.com/a/15469489/1056713) :-) It works correctly for prices (about 50% of the select elements), but I'd like to be able to use it for the remaining elements

Comment: Would you mind clarifying the changing you made to the js function (so that I can learn from my mistakes ;-))? And of course I would welcome a simpler way to handle the php :-D

Comment: I added some comments, but really is exactly what you were trying to do. Nothing extra. You can't just assign an array to an array or replace elements of an array the way you are trying to. You have to `unset` the elements first. I don't think this post will be helpful to anyone else... Wish you luck :)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying your improvements to the JS function a bit :-) I'm open to going about this another way in order to be able to use arrays, but I'm not following your suggestion to first unset the elements

Answer (score 0):

On your example page `option` is not found because initially there is no option that has `_default` in its value. You need to set one from start or edit your JS to include an option what to do, when there is no option found:

```
var option = $(this).find("option[value*=default]") ||  $(this).find("option:first-child");
```

But to be honest, I have no idea what you are trying to achieve with this code.

Comment: Your post made me realize that the problem is that the PHP 'helper' function isn't getting triggered, and I've updated the question.  The PHP 'helper' function  manipulates the string values if the db value included the suffix '_default') in order to create an option with '_default'.